# Producers Consumers Threads and Mutex

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

In relation to when producer accesses the shared source, Do I need another condition variable/condition signal? So it does get blocked when the shared resource is locked. I have a condition variable for the consumer, so it does it waits and if it won't try to access if there is nothing there to be added on (to  consume)

```
int pnum;  // number updated when producer runs.
int csum;  // sum computed using pnum when consumer runs.

int (*pred)(int); // predicate indicating number to be consumed
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

pthread_cond_t condc,condp;

int toConsume = 0; // condition varibale counter
int produceT() {
    //Start Critical Section
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    scanf("%d",&pnum);
    toConsume++;
    //End Critical Section
    pthread_cond_signal (&condc);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return pnum;
}

void *Produce(void *a) {
  int p;

  p=1;
  while (p) {
    printf("producer thinking...\n");
    sleep(1);
    printf("..done!\n");
    p = produceT();
    printf("PRODUCED %d\n",p);
  }
  printf("EXIT-P\n");
  pthread_exit(0);
}


int consumeT() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); //protect buffer
    while(toConsume <=0){ // if nothing in buffer then wait
        pthread_cond_wait(&condc,&mutex);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); //release buffer
    //sleep()
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); //protect buffer
    if ( pred(pnum) ) { csum += pnum; }
    toConsume--;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return pnum;
}

void *Consume(void *a) {
  int p;

  p=1;
  while (p) {
    printf("consumer thinking...\n");
    sleep(rand()%3);
    printf("..done!\n");
    p = consumeT();
    printf("CONSUMED %d\n",csum);
  }
  printf("EXIT-C\n");
  pthread_exit(0);
}


int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  // the current number predicate
  static pthread_t prod,cons;
    long rc;

  pred = &cond1;
  if (argc>1) {
    if      (!strncmp(argv[1],"2",10)) { pred = &cond2; }
    else if (!strncmp(argv[1],"3",10)) { pred = &cond3; }
  }
  pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL);
  pthread_cond_init(&condc,NULL);//Initialize consumer condition variable
  pthread_cond_init(&condp,NULL);//Initialize producer condition variable

  pnum = 999;
  csum=0;
  srand(time(0));

  printf("Creating Producer:\n");
    rc = pthread_create(&prod,NULL,Produce,(void *)0);
    if (rc) {
            printf("ERROR return code from pthread_create(prod): %ld\n",rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
  printf("Creating Consumer:\n");
    rc = pthread_create(&cons,NULL,Consume,(void *)0);
    if (rc) {
            printf("ERROR return code from pthread_create(cons): %ld\n",rc);
            exit(-1);
        }

    pthread_join( prod, NULL);
    pthread_join( cons, NULL);


  printf("csum=%d.\n",csum);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A conditional variable is a way of efficiently blocking a thread until a certain condition is verified.

You use a conditional variable in the consumer simply because you dictate you **can't consume if there isn't anything to consume** -- so you decide to block until there is something to consume. In your case, this happens when `toConsume == 0`.

You may dictate that the producer must also wait -- that's entirely up to your specification. Some ideas:

- You may want to prevent the variable to go over a certain value (e.g. `1000`, or `INT_MAX` to avoid overflow).
- If instead of a counter you use a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) to place your *things* to be consumed, the producer must wait if there are no free slots to place the *things* in the buffer. This is the most common way of teaching the producers-consumers in textbooks :)